# Find view within hierarchy with Android Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a dashboard with custom views.

I want to test that once the data is available, it properly gets displayed in the various text views.

My problem is: how do I select the various TextViews given they belong to a hierarchy.

Example: how to get `current_month > sales > value view`?

I know only how to do with a single hierarchy level but that does not help here:

```
onView(
  allOf(withId(R.id.value), 
  isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.current_month))))
```

The hierarchy looks like:

```
+- RelativeLayout
|
|___+ CustomCardView (id = current_month)
|   |
|   |___+ CustomValueView (id = sales)
|   |   |
|   |   |___+ TextView (id = value)
|   |   |
|   |   |___+ TextView (id = unit)
|   |
|   |___+ CustomValueView (id = earnings)
|       |
|       |___+ TextView (id = value)
|       |
|       |___+ TextView (id = unit)
|
|___+ CustomCardView (id = last_month)
|   |
|   |___+ CustomValueView (id = sales)
|   |   |
|   |   |___+ TextView (id = value)
|   |   |
|   |   |___+ TextView (id = unit)
|   |
|   |___+ CustomValueView (id = earnings)
|       |
|       |___+ TextView (id = value)
|       |
|       |___+ TextView (id = unit)
|
|___+ CustomCardView (id = all_time)
    |
    |___+ CustomValueView (id = sales)
    |   |
    |   |___+ TextView (id = value)
    |   |
    |   |___+ TextView (id = unit)
    |
    |___+ CustomValueView (id = earnings)
        |
        |___+ TextView (id = value)
        |
        |___+ TextView (id = unit)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok. Looks rather simple.

```
    onView(allOf(withId(R.id.value),
            isDescendantOfA(allOf(withId(R.id.sales),
                    isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.current_month))))))
```

Is that the best way?

Comment: Perhaps you can help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67199041/espresso-tap-on-specific-bottomnavigationbar-item

Answer (score 1):

Use `withParent(Matcher)` Hierarchy View Matcher:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.value),
     withParent(allOf(withId(R.id.sales),
          withParent(withId(R.id.current_month)))),
  isDisplayed()));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perhaps you can guide on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67199041/espresso-tap-on-specific-bottomnavigationbar-item